# FB Chat Extensions: Setting different home urls for test versions of an app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, chat, bots, facebook-messenger-bot

We're creating a bot and messenger exentension on Messenger. We have multiple test apps on fb developer. Setting different webhooks (via ngrok) allows us to trigger our app for every developer so that each can test his feature. So every time I talk with my bot, it replies four times. Useful for testing replies independently.

Is this sort of workflow avaiable for the chat extensions? Currently we set the home Url using the curl command below. But all the devs will get that home URL - they each want to set their own somehow.

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d ' {
"home_url" : {
 "url": "https://xxxx.ngrok.io/extension/welcome",
 "webview_height_ratio": "tall",
 "webview_share_button": "hide",
 "in_test":true
}
}' "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messenger_profile?access_token=xxxxxD"
```

any ideas, greaty appreciated

Guy

Comment: No, that is not possible, since this is a page-related setting. If you want that as well, then each dev would have to use the bot on an individual page as well.

Comment: Ok, good to know thanks